# How to convert string number into numeric number with given string, Java

Tags: java

I would like to extract number from a given string sentence and convert into a numeric value.
For example,

Input: "Hello I have two passwords with dk12kdkd and 2kdkae5."

output: "Hello I have two passwords with dkONETWOkdkd and TWOkdkaeFIVE."

I am confused with how to extract numbers and change value to get back original one.

Thanks for the help!

```
public class Main {

  public static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testString = "Hello I have two passwords with dk12kdkd and 25kdkae5.";
    String singleDigits[] = {"ZERO", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE",
            "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE"};


    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        str = str.replace(matcher.group(),
                String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()));
    } // confused from here.
}
```

Comment: I added the solution using your approach (Matcher)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suggestion matches your approach with matching regex using `Matcher` and `Pattern`

Apply a regex to extract the digits, then replace each one with the matching index from the array using `replace()` method.

Online demo
 http://tpcg.io/qYIn6e6h

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    static String singleDigits[] = {"ZERO", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE",
            "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String regex = "(\\d+)";
        String testString = "Hello I have two passwords with dk12kdkd and 25kdkae5.";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testString);

        while ( matcher.find() ) {
            testString = testString.replaceFirst(matcher.group(1), getDigitsText(matcher.group(1)) );
        }
        System.out.println( testString);
    }

 /**
 * Gets the text representation of the given number.
 * Example:  Input: 39 outputs: THREENINE
 */
    public static String getDigitsText( String digitText ){
        //split digits if more than one digit. split("") works since Java 8
        String[] digitStrings = digitText.split("");
        //get digit for string
        String text = "";
        for (String digitString : digitStrings){
            //parase string to int
            int digit = Integer.parseInt(digitString);
            //get matching text from 
            text += singleDigits[digit];
        }

        return text;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Hello I have two passwords with dkONETWOkdkd and TWOFIVEkdkaeFIVE.

**Approach**

- Used Matcher and Pattern to extract digits from String using regex (\d+)
- Regex returns every number portion inside that String, it could be multiple digits.
- This method `getDigitsText()` will take that String, split it into an array of Strings, each element represents one character that must be a digit.
- Then iterate the array, getting the name of number from the `singleDigits[]` array
- The method concats the name and returns the text representation of the given number.
- The matcher loop inside main will simply replace the digits String with names String built in the method.
- Result is printed after loop finishes.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testString = "Hello I have two passwords with dk12kdkd and 25kdkae5.";
        String singleDigits[] = { "ZERO", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE" };
        HashMap<String, String> dict = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < singleDigits.length; i++) {
            dict.put(String.valueOf(i), singleDigits[i]);
        }
        for (char s : testString.toCharArray()) {
            if (dict.containsKey(String.valueOf(s))) 
                testString = testString.replace(String.valueOf(s), dict.get(String.valueOf(s)));
        }
        System.out.println(testString);
    }
}
```

> Output

`Hello I have two passwords with dkONETWOkdkd and TWOFIVEkdkaeFIVE.`

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think I’d use a regular expression for this. I am offering three avenues:

1. The easy way: for each digit from 0 through 9, replace every occurrence.
2. Build the result in a `StringBuilder`. For each char in the original string append the appropriate word if it’s a digit, otherwise just the char.
3. A fix to your regex approach.

### Replace all digits

I have put your declaration outside the method (you don’t have to do that):

```
private static final String SINGLE_DIGITS[] = { "ZERO", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE",
        "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE" };
```

Now we do:

```
    String testString = "Hello I have two passwords with dk12kdkd and 25kdkae5.";

    for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
        testString = testString.replace(String.valueOf(d), SINGLE_DIGITS[d]);
    }
    System.out.println(testString);
```

Output:

> Hello I have two passwords with dkONETWOkdkd and TWOFIVEkdkaeFIVE.

When some digit is not found (for example, `0`), `replace()` just returns the same string (or an equal one, I don’t care). If on the other hand a digit occurs more than once (both `2` and `5` do), every occurrence is replaced. This is not the most efficient way, but for strings the size of yours you should be fine.

### Build result linearly

I am using these further declarations:

```
private static final BitSet DIGITS = new BitSet();
static {
    DIGITS.set('0', '9' + 1);
}
```

Now we can do:

```
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int ix = 0; ix < testString.length(); ix++) {
        char ch = testString.charAt(ix);
        if (DIGITS.get(ch)) {
            buf.append(SINGLE_DIGITS[Character.getNumericValue(ch)]);
        } else {
            buf.append(ch);
        }
    }
    String result = buf.toString();

    System.out.println(result);
```

Output is the same as before. This is the recommended way if efficiency is a priority.

### Your approach with regex

First, since you want `12` replaced by `ONETWO`(not `TWELVE`), don’t include a `+` in your regular expression:

```
public static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d");
```

Now for each digit found, make a lookup in `SINGLE_DIGITS` to find the replacement:

```
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testString);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        testString = testString.replace(matcher.group(),
                SINGLE_DIGITS[Integer.parseInt(matcher.group())]);
    }

    System.out.println(testString);
```

The output is the same as before.